# How to deal with Python slice objects in boost::python?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, slice, boost-python

Suppose there is a class `MyArray` in C++. It implements an array of `SomeType` In order to make a `__getitem__` function for it in Python, I do something like this

```
const SomeType& getitem(const MyArray *arr, PyObject *slice) {
    // ???
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule) 
{
    class_<MyArray>("MyArray")
    .def("__getitem__", &getitem)
    // probably some other methods...
    ;
}
```

It is possible to get indices in `slice` by using [these functions](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/slice.html). However, "[Boost::Python is designed with the idea in mind that users never touch a PyObject*](https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/GettingStarted)".

Is there a better 'boost way' to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost.Python is designed to minimize the need to interact with `PyObject`, and it often accomplishes this by:

- Providing higher-level type wrappers.
- Allowing access to the Python object's interface through the associated `boost::python::object`.

For example, one can access the Python object's interface through C++ in a similar manner as  one would do in Python.  The following demonstrates accessing the `start` attribute of a `boost::python::object` that refers to a Python `slice` instance:

```cpp
namespace python = boost::python;
python::object slice = get_slice_object();
python::object start = slice.attr("start");
std::size_t start_index = !start.is_none()
  ? python::extract<std::size_t>(start) // Extract index.
  : 0;                                  // Default.
```

While this approach works, it tends to result in much boilerplate code: creating defaults when `None` is provided, handling zero-length slices, and converting negative indexes to positive index.  In this case, Boost.Python provides a higher-level type wrapper [`boost::python::slice`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/python/doc/v2/slice.html) that has a `get_indices()` member-function that will remove much of the boilerplate code.  Here is a complete minimal example:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/range/irange.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/slice.hpp>

/// @brief Mockup class that creates a range from 0 to N.
struct counter
{
  counter(std::size_t n)
  {
    data.reserve(n);
    boost::copy(boost::irange(std::size_t(0), n), std::back_inserter(data));
  }

  std::vector<int> data;
};

/// @brief Handle slicing for counter object.
boost::python::list spam_getitem(
  const counter& self,
  boost::python::slice slice)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::list result;

  // Boost.Python will throw std::invalid_argument if the range would be
  // empty.
  python::slice::range<std::vector<int>::const_iterator> range;
  try
  {
    range = slice.get_indices(self.data.begin(), self.data.end());
  }
  catch (std::invalid_argument)
  {
    return result;
  }

  // Iterate over fully-closed range.
  for (; range.start != range.stop; std::advance(range.start, range.step))
  {
    result.append(*range.start);
  }
  result.append(*range.start); // Handle last item.
  return result;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;
  python::class_<counter>("Counter", python::init<int>())
    .def("__getitem__", &spam_getitem)
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
>>> from example import Counter
>>> counter = Counter(5)
>>> assert(counter[:]    == [0,1,2,3,4])
>>> assert(counter[:-2]  == [0,1,2])
>>> assert(counter[-2:]  == [3,4])
>>> assert(counter[::2]  == [0,2,4])
>>> assert(counter[1::2] == [1,3])
>>> assert(counter[100:] == [])
```

Comment: Great example! Can this be extended to deal with both slices and indices (e.g., counter[2:-1] and counter[2])?